# Why tweepy.Cursor is returning empty file when it should not

Tags: python, api, twitter, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl down tweets from Netherlands through twitter api, but it returns an empty file and does not show any bug. I know people in Netherlands speak English and use twitter so it does not make sense. Here is my code:

The set up part (should be fine):

```
import tweepy
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

key_file = 'keys.json'
# Loading your keys from keys.json (which you should have filled
# in in question 1):
with open(key_file) as f:
    keys = json.load(f)
# if you print or view the contents of keys be sure to delete the cell!
consumer_key = keys["consumer_key"]
consumer_secret = keys["consumer_secret"]
access_token = keys["access_token"]
access_token_secret = keys["access_token_secret"]
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

Here is the function I wrote to get data:

```
def tweet_obtainer(file_name,key_word = None, language = None,  tweet_since, tweet_until
               , geo = None, place = None, tweet_mode = 'extended', retweet = 'false', number_of_tweet = 100):

    ds_tweets_save_path = file_name + '.json'
    example_tweets = [t._json for t in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q= key_word,
        lang= language,
        since= tweet_since,
        until= tweet_until,
        geocode = geo,
        place= place,
        tweet_mode= tweet_mode,
        retweet = retweet#-filter:nativeretweets 
    ).items(number_of_tweet)]#number of tweets

    with open(ds_tweets_save_path, "w") as f:        
        json.dump(example_tweets, f)
    with open(ds_tweets_save_path, "r") as f:
        example_tweets = json.load(f)

    return None
```

Here is the line where I implement it on the Netherlands and then I get an empty file which is blizzard:

```
tweet_obtainer("data_netherlands", ["is"],"en","2018-06-01", 
    "2018-06-14",geo = "52.1326, 5.2913, 131km"
)
```

Any English tweet should contain "is" so It should not return empty file!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It is because my geocode string has space in it. There should be no space but only comma between lat, long and radius.